# Creating a second patch on a managed package

Tags: patch

On our managed package, we created and released a patch on the latest version  Eg:- major release version - 2.1. Patch released - 2.1.1

I am working on another escalation and I would like to create a second patch (2.1.2) on the same major release version (2.1). Is this not possible?
When I tried to create a patch org, I am only seeing major release versions upto 2.1 (but not 2.1) in the drop down. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a Patch Org for a major release (such as 2.1), each release you upload on that patch org will be a patch for that major release. You should be able to upload your new version on the patch org, and it will increment the patch number for you to 2.1.2. You do not need to create a new patch org for each patch, just for each major release that you want to make patches for.

Comment: Glad I could help, @sfdev! If you are satisfied with this answer, don't forget to mark it as accepted.